# Android: How to use classes in a different file

Tags: android, class, external

I'm trying to make a handler class for many of my reusable methods.  I'm having problems interfacing the separate class file.

Can someone tell me what this example fails or what would have to be done to make it work?

ClassExampleActivity.java:
    package com.apollo.classexample;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ClassExampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    TextView infotext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        String infostring = "Main Activity Class\n";

        Myhandler mh = new Myhandler();
        infostring += mh.testmethod();

        // Trying to use the TextView widget from this MyHandler class
        // This works from the main class but fails in the MyHandler class
        TextView infotext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infotext);
        infotext.setText(infostring);
    }
}
```

Myhandler.java:
    package com.apollo.classexample;

```
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class Myhandler extends Activity {

    public String testmethod(){
        String innermessage = "This is a message from the innerclass\n";
        System.out.println(innermessage);

            /* This is an important component that I would like to use in this class
             Commenting these lines out and the application doesn't crash.
             I'm trying to learn how to use the next two lines in this MyHandler 
             class which I'm trying to make portable and reusable for other
             projectes.
            */
        TextView infotext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infotext);
            infotext.setText(innermessage); 

            // Placed to show that the MyHandler class is actually accessed
        return innermessage;
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.apollo.classexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ClassExampleActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="MyHandler" />
        <activity android:name="MyCRUDSQL" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

When calling the testmethod() the android app will crash.  If I comment it out it'll run and print the System.out.printlin() message to the LogCat.

LogCat:

```
03-20 17:03:42.783: I/System.out(654): This is a message from the innerclass
03-20 17:03:42.783: D/AndroidRuntime(654): Shutting down VM
03-20 17:03:42.803: W/dalvikvm(654): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.apollo.classexample/com.apollo.classexample.ClassExampleActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1744)
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at com.apollo.classexample.MyHandler.testmethod(MyHandler.java:16)
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at com.apollo.classexample.ClassExampleActivity.onCreate(ClassExampleActivity.java:23)
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: don't use myhandler mh = new myhandler(); for Activity.

Comment: Before Initializing the the layout in OnCreate() method You can not make the intance of activity you probably have to start Activity override the oncreate method set its content by SetContentView()  And then set properties of its views.

Comment: Nitin I'm working on the project trying to implement what you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

1. Change the name myhandler to '**MyHandler**', that sounds nice..
2. In present situation you dont need to extend Activity class in **MyHandler**.
3. You are setting text value twice delete following lines from testmethod they are not needed their..

TextView infotext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infotext);

```
    infotext.setText(innermessage);
```

try and update your question if you get any error....

**EDIT**

```
   //MyHandler.java
   public class Myhandler {

        public void testMethod(TextView txtView){
            String innermessage = "This is a message from the innerclass.";            
            txtView.setText(innerMessage); 

        }

    }
```

// ClassExampleActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ClassExampleActivity extends Activity {


    TextView infotext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        String infostring = "Main Activity Class\n";
        TextView infotext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infotext);
        infotext.setText(infostring);

        Myhandler mh = new Myhandler();
        mh.testMethod(infoText);


    }
}
```

This should work!!

Comment: 1) I changed the myhandler to MyHandler
    2) App totally fails when remvoing extend Activity.
    3) The line "TextView infotext = (TextView) findViewByID(R.id.infotext)" is needed to specify where the text go.  “infotext.setText(innermessage);” inserts the text.  This isn't duplication.

Comment: edited the answer, to add a working code, which works on GingerBird!! Please add the error message (or LogCat msg ) if it doesn't for u...

Comment: Amit.  Your code works exactly like mine.  I don't have any problems, and never had any problems with the “return” statement that you included.  I used that to show that the class was being accessed.

My problem and question is how to use TextView in the class.  That is what produces errors.  I'm trying to make reusable classes.

I can use the TextView feature in the ClassExampleActivity.java class.  But I can't figure out how to use it in the MyHandler.java class without the app crashing.

Thank!

Comment: The LogCat output is appended to the original message.

Comment: @plz see the edited code.... I have added a TextView as a reference parameter to the testMethod().... Hope that works!!!

Comment: It doesn't work.  It gives the same error.

If it did run without errors (which again, I modified it exactly as you posted and tested it), the resolution wouldn't fit the question/objective.

The textMethod() method is an example of the methods that will become part of the Myhandler class, which I hope to be self-sufficient and portable.

Examples of other intended methods are: createdatabase(), showallrecs(), updaterecord(String rec), deleterecord(String rec), showsinglerec(), etc.

Answer (score 1):

I answer here, so you can see better my explanation.

In MyHandler class, you do the follow:

```
TextView infotext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infotext);
```

As you can see in the Android Reference:

> public View findViewById (int id)
>
> Since: API Level 1 Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle).
> Returns The view if found or null otherwise.

As I can understand there you haven't process any XML in MyHandler class, so you can't take the TextView from the XML and It is always null.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I'm sure you're on the right track.

I thought the view definition was inherited.

Please forgive me for taking so in responding, but I have been trying to find out how to add this view definition to the MyHandler class.

I'm trying to organize my various attempts at this and figure out a good way to show you.  I'll post examples ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check if infotext is NULL?.

Comment: The same lines (syntax) for accessing the infotext is used in the classexampleactivity.java file.  The infotext gets set with the infotext.setText() method.  If it's null, what can I do to make it stop crashing and actually load the innermessage string parameter it's given?

Comment: Gutiory.  Looking at the LogCat I attached to the original message it appears that there is some problem concerning null:

    03-20 17:03:42.853: E/AndroidRuntime(654): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Do you have any idea why there is a NullPointerException?  As you can see the "innermessage" isn't a null string.  You can tell because it can actually return the string to the main class.  Is the infotext receiving the type set by:

    TextView infotext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infotext);

Answer (score 0):

Have you remembered to add both activities to your AndroidManifest.xml?
That's caught me out on more than one or two occasions.

Comment: I hadn't remembered or known to put an entry into the AndroidManifest.xml file.  I studied how and placed the entry.  This doesn't help.  I'll be added the AndrodManifest.xml file to the code of the original question above.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to work with classes .. in Android

because of you ..

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment 1:

You should replace .. myhandler .. with .. MyHandler

Comment 2:

You should copy-past .. the block .. (from AndroidManifest.xml)

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ClassExampleActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and replace ".ClassExampleActivity" with ".MyHandler"

to get

```
    <activity
        android:name="pak.iceplanets.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="pak.iceplanets.MyHandler"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment 3

ClassExampleActivity.java .. and .. Myhandler.java

must be in .. the same folder ..

(classexample .. from the folder .. apolo .. from the folder .. com)

You may replace .. ".MyHandler" .. with "com.apollo.classexample.MyHandler"

Comment 4 My files

MyHandler.java .. and .. MainActivity.java

are both .. in the folder .. iceplanets .. from the folder .. pak

Comment 5 The content .. of my file

MyHandler.java .. is below

package pak.iceplanets;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyHandler extends Activity {

```
public void testMethod(TextView txtView){

    String innerMessage = "This is a message from the innerclass.";            

    txtView.setText(innerMessage); 
}
```

}

Comment 6

Because I use Eclipse

I automatically .. write  .. in the folder .. activity_main.xml

I obtained the lines

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment 7 To use (the class) MyHandler

I wrote (.. in MainActivity.java)

the lines ..

MyHandler mh;

TextView infoText;

after the line

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

...

I also wrote ( .. in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ )

the lines

```
 // infoText .. is a reference to .. textView1       

 TextView infoText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);      

 MyHandler mh = new MyHandler();

 mh.testMethod(infoText);
```

after .. the line .. setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

.....

My pieces of the code .. I wrote above ..

works well .. on my computer.

Success

Best regards, Tonio