# Method for SQLite within other other .java file.How to use

Tags: android, sqlite, methods

I want to coding a app with SQLite.There are two java file, one is Main.java, the other one is MyDB.java.
All method about DB ,I want to put on MyDB.java
I don't know how to use method in MyDB.java.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to read this tutorial.

http://www.roseindia.net/java/javascript-array/call-method-another-class.shtml
or  this

[Android: How to use classes in a different file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767657/android-how-to-use-classes-in-a-different-file)

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Java classes and objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).

Basically you could set the MyDB as an attribute for the Main class (if it it's an object class also), and initialize it within Main. Then you can use the MyDb-object's methods.

Or just create an object out of MyDb in your Main-function (`MyDB db = new MyDB(...)`) and start calling its methods (e.g. `db.getConnection()`)